# BD por defecto en Vtiger CRM 6.0.0

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día, estoy usando [Vtiger CRM 6.0.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtigercrm/files/vtiger%20CRM%206.0.0/Core%20Product/)

Tengo el CRM, pero no tengo la BD, y tampoco puedo instalar uno nuevo.
Lo que necesito son las instrucciones que crean la estructura y los datos.

Alguien sabe como crear la BD por defecto sin usar el proceso de instalación?

Comment: Creo que como mínimo vas a necesitar clonar la BD de una instalación limpia. ¿Puedes hacer la instalación en otra máquina y exportar la BD?

Comment: @Orici Justo ahora estoy respaldando la BD de vtigercrm600.exe, de todas formas, la idea mía era saber en donde se hace la creación de estructura y datos, para poder hacerlo con cualquier otro CRM sin instalarlo.

Comment: En ese caso es bastante probable que cada CRM internamente este construido de manera diferenciada a como lo están otros, teniendo más en común en cuanto a funcionalidades.